# cannot find my installed application on LDplayer why?

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

[image]i have a TV android application created on android studio, when i run it into LDplayer cannot find the icon of it in the whole emulator. It is installed successfully but my problem is i cannot find the icon
anyone know why?

the image show how there is no any app installed, but i just run it from android studio and it is successfully installed !!

below the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/banner"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Leanback"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    <activity android:name=".ui.search.SearchActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.player.PlayerActivity"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:targetApi="m" />
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.main.LandingActivity"
        android:banner="@drawable/banner"
        android:icon="@drawable/banner"
        android:logo="@drawable/banner"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ui.detail.DetailActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".ui.main.MainActivity" />
</application>
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.software.leanback"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
    android:required="false" />
```

Comment: "cannot find the icon of it in the whole emulator" -- where are you looking? Do you mean that you cannot find it in the launcher?

Comment: the icon is not found in the home page of emulator also cannot find it on system apps folder

Comment: LDPlayer does not look like it is an Android TV emulator. So, what you put in your manifest for your Android TV app may not work there, just as it may not work in a phone. You might consider providing the portion of your `AndroidManifest.xml` file that contains your launcher activity, as part of a [mcve].

Comment: please can you check the manifest, i updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

```xml
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

That will work for Android TV and perhaps other TV platforms (e.g., Amazon Fire TV). It will not work for ordinary Android devices, and that will include most emulators. You need to add a second `<intent-filter>` — the standard one that you see in just about every Android app:

```xml
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

That assumes that you want the same activity to be used as the launcher activity on phones as well as TVs. If you want a different activity to be the launcher activity on phones, put the `LAUNCHER` `<intent-filter>` on it.

Conversely, it may be that you only want to support TVs. That's fine, but then you will want to limit yourself to emulators that are actually emulating an Android TV or similar environment.